# Sort elements from an array based on the proximity to a given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var objects = [
  {id: "obj1",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 125
   }]
  }, 
  {id: "obj2",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 350
   }]
  }, 
  {id: "obj3",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 500
   }]
  }, 
  {id: "obj4",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 1000
   }]
  }
]

var numberdifference = 498;
```

I want to sort the objects being on top the object which value is closer to `numberdifference`

```
var sorteditems = objects.sort((a, b) => {   
     if(a.id.match('heal') && b.id.match('heal')) {
      let diff1 = bothpdiff-a.feat[0].value;
      let diff2 = bothpdiff-b.feat[0].value;
       
      return diff1 - diff2;
    });
    
    console.log(sorteditems);
```

But I can't make it work. In this example obj3 should be on top followed by obj2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.abs()` to measure distance:

```js
var sorteditems = objects.sort((a, b) => {   
      let diff1 = Math.abs(numbereddifference-a.feat[0].value);
      let diff2 = Math.abs(numbereddifference-b.feat[0].value);
       
      return diff1 - diff2;
    });
    
    console.log(sorteditems)
```

Also remove condition with 'heal', because it's wrong (flow never goes there). Better to use filter to remove all elements without the 'heal' as id

Comment: thank you, very nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do with `a.id.match('heal')` but I'll point out that `a.id` is `"obj1"`, not `"heal"`. Also, `bothpdiff` isn't defined in your example.

You can sort them by subtracting the absolute difference between `value` and `numberdifference` for the items to be compared.

```js
var objects = [
  {id: "obj1",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 125
   }]
  }, 
  {id: "obj2",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 350
   }]
  }, 
  {id: "obj3",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 500
   }]
  }, 
  {id: "obj4",
   feat: [{
    id: "heal",
    value: 1000
   }]
  }
]

var numberdifference = 498;

const sorted = objects.sort(({feat: a}, {feat: b}) => {
  return Math.abs(numberdifference - a[0].value) - Math.abs(numberdifference - b[0].value);
})

console.log(sorted); // 500, 350, 125, 1000
```

Comment: Good alternative, thanks.